# Regular expressions ignoring a file extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with a regular expression. I have the following 4 file names

> heapdump.20160406.214053.18914.0013.phd
>   heapdump.20160406.214053.18914.0013.phd.gz
>   javacore.20160406.214053.18914.0002.txt
>   javacore.20160406.214053.18914.0002.txt.gz

Basically what I need is for my regular expression to ignore the files with the .gz on the end of it. I tried the following but it does not seem to work.

```
/heapdump.*.phd|javacore.*.txt/i
/heapdump*.phd|javacore*.txt/i
/heapdump.\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+.phd|javacore.\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+.txt/i
```

Thanks

Comment: `.` in the above case refers to the `any character except new line`  .To use period use `\.` That seems to be the mistake.Tell me if this works.

Comment: `!/^.*\.gz$/.test(filename)` ?

Comment: This question gives me a feeling that you are from Iran, Am I right?

Comment: @Shafizadeh and why is that? is there any predictive algorithm that you are using based on questions to determine the country of user?..)

Comment: @rock321987 No there isn't any specific algorithm. Actually OP's  *English-writing* tells me he is from Iran .. However that's just a guess, do not take it seriously.

Comment: @Shafizadeh I was just kidding..but if there is any way, I would be very much interested in knowing that algorithm..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much you want the solution to be precise. If you only have `phd` and `txt` extensions this will work

```
/heapdump.*\.(phd|txt)$/
```

Which means: *a string starting with heapdump, followed by whatever, then a dot, then phd or txt, end of line*

Or you can simply negate *a string that ends with dot gz*

```
/.*\.gz$/
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work

```
(?!.*\.gz$)(^.*$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jR1iH3/1)**

*JS Code*

```js
var re = /(?!.*\.gz$)(^.*$)/gm; 
var str = 'heapdump.20160406.214053.18914.0013.phd\nheapdump.20160406.214053.18914.0013.phd.gz\njavacore.20160406.214053.18914.0002.txt\njavacore.20160406.214053.18914.0002.txt.gz';

var result = str.match(re);
document.writeln(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option which does not require using a regular expression would be to split the filename on period (`.`) into an array, and then check if the last element of the array contains the extension `gz`:

```
var filename = "heapdump.20160406.214053.18914.0013.phd.gz";
var parts = filename.split(".");

if (parts[parts.length - 1] == 'gz') {
    alert("ignore this file");
}
else {
    alert("pay attention to this file");
}
```